# Where is permalink in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to switch my permalink from "Plain" to get my Wordpress REST API working. But every tutorial shows people going to settings>permalink to change it, why isnt it showing up. Apparently it inst showing up on pro accounts as of 6 days ago.
[My Word Press Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAN8G.png)

I tried searching through wordpress, newer tutorials, could not find anything.

Comment: It should be right after Media. Maybe talk to your host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change permalink on Wordpress.com, Wordpress.org supports permalink change.